# How to concatenate between two variables?

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I need to include the `-` to my database whenever I select the year, but only, `2006 2008` are saving in my database. How is this guys?

```
('<option value="'.$year2. " " . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2.' - '.$i.'</option>'."\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the value attribute, like this:

```
('<option value="'.$year2. " - " . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2.' - '.$i.'</option>'."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should put the `-` in the **value** attribute and not just the label text.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
'<option value="'.$year2. " " . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2." - ".$i.'</option>'."\n";
```